# How to show the value of an attribute in shopping cart?

Tags: magento

I added an attribute 'items' having input type textbox in admin.I want to show the value of that attribute in shopping cart.For that i have added this code in  `template/checkout/cart/sidebar-top.phtml` which is below:

```
<?php 
        $productId = $_item->getId();
        $productInfo = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId); 
        echo $productInfo->getAttributeText('product_type'); 
?>
```

but when i am adding this above code showing

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object
```

if anyone knows this,please help me out.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
$productId = $_item->getProduct()->getId();
$productInfo = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId); 
echo $productInfo->getAttributeText('product_type');
```

Comment: I have added this code then showing the error
Fatal error: Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object

Comment: Can you checkout $_item->getCount();

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about custom option or simple attribute?

For Simple attribute (text) and if you are on product page try belo code:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

If you are not on the product page then you can use the below code, load the product by sku and get your attribute value

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku());
echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontEnd()->getValue($product);
```

Comment: when i added the above code showing Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object

Comment: are you really calling the product object and getting product data as required ?

Comment: I have added an attribute in admin 'items' having input type 'textbox'.whatever the value i will add in admin, it should show in shopping cart....thats much
and whatever code you have given above,i used in page and showing the error Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object

Comment: get_class($this); and see what class type is it.

Comment: plz tell me the solution it is very urgent